# get WPF WebBrowser HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, browser

I'm using Wpf WebBrowser to access a certain page. I need to get it's HTML content- I can't use Webclient or WebReques etc. because I need to execute JS on that pages. I also tried Awesomium and Wf WebBrowser (both wrong).

```
    dynamic doc=browser.Document;
    var text=doc.InnerHtml//or something like this
```

Code above doesn't work for me, it shows nullreference.
Can anybody tell me how to fetch it? I've been searching for this for weeks and didn't find anything really working :/ . Please answer like for a biggest dumbass you can imagine :D. It sometimes happens to me that people send me a piece of code and I have no idea how to use it... I mean please make your posts like ending with

```
     string HTML=some_stuff;
```

Or if you know about some alternative browser which is not buggy and where I can access HTML or something that would let me execute JS on loaded Html with affects like cookies and changes in HTML source that's also a really good answer.
I'll be appreciative for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made something like this once. It was horrible, but it works.

You need to add a reference to [`Microsoft.mshtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317(v=vs.85).aspx).

Then you can use [`IHTMLDocument2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mshtml.ihtmldocument2(v=vs.110).aspx). Why 2? Good question... anyway, I wrote a couple of helper functions like this:

```
public static void FillField(object doc, string id, string value)
{
    var element = findElementByID(doc, id);
    element.setAttribute("value", value);
}

public static void ClickButton(object doc, string id)
{
    var element = findElementByID(doc, id);
    element.click();
}

private static IHTMLElement findElementByID(object doc, string id)
{
    IHTMLDocument2 thisDoc;
    if (!(doc is IHTMLDocument2))
        return null;
    else
        thisDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)doc;

    var element = thisDoc.all.OfType<IHTMLElement>()
        .Where(n => n != null && n.id != null)
        .Where(e => e.id == id).First();
    return element;
}
```

### Executing JS

```
private static void ExecuteScript(object doc, string js)
{
    IHTMLDocument2 thisDoc;
    if (!(doc is IHTMLDocument2))
        return;
    else
        thisDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)doc;
    thisDoc.parentWindow.execScript(js);
}
```

I call them like this...

```
HtmlDocumentHelper.FillField(webBrowser.Document, <id>, <value>);
HtmlDocumentHelper.FillField(webBrowser.Document, <id>, <value>);
HtmlDocumentHelper.ClickButton(webBrowser.Document, <id>);
HtmlDocumentHelper.ExecuteScript(webBrowser.Document, "alert(1);");
```

Comment: Thank you for mshtml and IHTMLDocument2!

Answer (score 11):

Yeeeaaaah! I did it. It's so simple:

```
    string HTML = (browser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2).body.outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

When I tried @Gray or @czubehead's code `body` was always null. The following code, however, worked for me:

```
dynamic webBrowserDocument = webBrowser.Document;
string html = webBrowserDocument?.documentElement?.InnerHtml;
```

And make sure that this should go into `LoadCompleted` or later. When using this in `Navigated` the source is not complete or even `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try wpf WebBrowser method called InvokeScript()?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string HTML = webBrowser.InvokeScript(@"document.getElementsByTagName ('html')[0].innerHTML").ToString();
```