# How to click browser and input into textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

How I can click buttons with ids or anything other, input to text box string etc. I know in windows form is easy with getelementbyid. But in WPF I cant find anything. I know how get source to string but I cant make click. Any ideas how do this or is even possible? I can get list of Ids from source +regex. Or is there too something I can get simply list? Need something like this:

```
HtmlElement button = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lButtonSearch");
button.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(GotoSearchPage);
```

I can do something like this but what next, how display it?

```
 System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser weba = newSystem.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
 weba.Navigate(new Uri("www.google.com"));
 string testowo = "btnI";
 System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement htmlElement = weba.Document.GetElementById(testowo);   
 htmlElement.InvokeMember("click");
```

How now convert it to display lets say WebBrowser id is =browserwindows

```
browserwindow=weba
```

wont work

Comment: If you want to switch from Forms to WPF, why are you relying on `System.Windows.Forms` (... `WebBrowser`, `HtmlElement`)?

Comment: because i dont know is any way to do something like Document.GetElementById(testowo) in WPF

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25557474/5265292

Comment: FillField is work but what do if button dont have id, just name? :)

Comment: I gave you a starting point into the world of MSHTML types, I don't plan to serve you any tiny bit of information on a silver plate. Read the documentation, use the documented interfaces - you will find some possibly matching interfaces that allow you to check for names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var doc = webBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
var button = doc.all.OfType<IHTMLInputElement>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.name == "btnG");

if(button != null)
{
    ((IHTMLElement)button).click();
}
```